# Protractor: Resolved promise is still being rejected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, protractor, automated-tests

I'm a beginner at using Protractor and I'm using it to create a simple test automation for an add-in in Outlook.

I'm currently testing these steps:

- Open an email
- Click add-in button

The issue is, in one of my functions (openEmail) that uses `browser.wait`, the promise returned by it is rejected after being resolved.

**utility.js**

```
function waitElement(method, { container, selector, timer }) {
  let _element = container ?
    container.$(selector) : $(selector);

  return browser.wait(
    protractor.ExpectedConditions[method](_element),
    1000 * (timer || 1),
    'Unable to wait for the element'

  ).then((() => _element));
}

isClickable(options) {
  return waitElement('elementToBeClickable', options);
}
```

**outlook.js**

```
let _ = require('./utility.js');

function openEmail(email) {
  _.isClickable({
    selector: email,
    timer: 15

  }).then(() => {
    console.log('OPEN EMAIL - CLICKABLE');
    el.click();

  }).catch(() => {
    throw Error('unable to click email.');
  });
}

function signIn(credentials) {
  let usernameField = $('#cred_userid_inputtext');
  let passwordField = $('#cred_password_inputtext');

  usernameField.sendKeys(credentials.username);
  passwordField.sendKeys(credentials.password);

  _.isClickable({
    selector: '#cred_sign_in_button',
    timer: 5

  }).then(el => {
    console.log('SIGN IN - CLICKABLE');
    el.click();

  }).catch(() => {
    throw Error('unable to click sign in button.');
  });
}
```

**test.js**

```
let outlook = require('./outlook.js');

describe('log in', () => {

  beforeAll(() => {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.get('https://outlook.office.com');

    // credentials & cssSelector are somewhere above the file
    outlook.signIn(credentials);
    outlook.openEmail(cssSelector);
  });

  it('should display log in', () => {
    // some tests here
  });

});
```

In my terminal, it logs `SIGN IN - CLICKABLE` and `OPEN EMAIL - CLICKABLE` but it also shows the error thrown by `openEmail` - `unable to click email.` I'm confused because `browser.wait` returns a promise, and AFAIK a resolved promise can not be rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `openEmail(email)` method, your `el` seems to be missing. I think your code should be

```
 function openEmail(email) {
    _.isClickable({
selector: email,
timer: 15

}).then(el => {
console.log('OPEN EMAIL - CLICKABLE');
el.click();

}).catch(() => {
throw Error('unable to click email.');
});
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, that's the cause, just a stupid mistake. Thanks